# Is there a way to bind a variable type to column data type?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, oracle, t-sql

In Oracle PL/SQL, you can always bind your code variables' type to a specific table.column type like this:

```
myVar TABLE.COLUMN%TYPE
```

So, if you change the column's type, you don't have to go over your code to re-define related var types (of course you'd still need to check you are properly using the variable).

Is there a similar way to define this in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is one, I'd like to know but in my experience so far:

- %TYPE
- %ROWTYPE

...are not supported and do not have alternatives in TSQL.

Comment: It would have been too good to be true if these alternatives existed. Thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in SQL Server.

Closest I can think of is to use a user-defined type to "mask" the underlying type. But IMHO that's not ideal for what you want.
Or there's [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspxtypes.) which is:

> A data type that stores values of
>   various SQL Server-supported data
>   types.

But, again this would really be a cludge (with limitations).

Answer (score 0):

If you are desparate, you could use the "sql_variant" data type. However, it can be awkward to use, and has always seemed to be a kludge to me.